# Position a span at the left of a centered textarea without changing the alignment

Tags: html, alignment, center

The title in a h1 tag is centered in the viewport.
Then, there is a textarea that is aligned with the title and centered too in the viewport.
How can I position a span with a number (12 for instance) at the left of the textarea without changing the centering of the textarea?

`enter code here`

## This title is centered in the viewport

12
        This textarea should be centered and aligned      with the title

https://jsfiddle.net/fredericmarcel/85f4mouk/26/

Answer (score 0):

You can add an inner div within your absolutely-positioned box element. This can then be set as position:relative to reset the positioning context and then the span can be positioned relative to that.

```
.inner{
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
}
.element .number {
  position:absolute; display:inline-block; 
  width:60px; height:60px; top:50%; margin-top:-30px;

  text-align:center; font-size:300%; 
  line-height:60px; vertical-align:middle;
}

<div class="box">
  <h1>This title is centered in the viewport </h1>
  <div class="element">
    <div class="inner">
       <span class="number">12</span>
        <textarea id="zonetexte">This textarea should be centered and aligned with the title</textarea>
      </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w3Lfu6q4/)